# Adding signature to an automated outlook mail

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to add signature at the end of the automated mails I am sending. I want the signature to be the default signature of the user that runs the macro. The code I have written runs without crushing but does not insert the signature. I am providing the code below.

```
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim currentDate As Date
Dim DeliveryDate As String
Dim Recipients As String
Dim CarbonCopy As String
Dim Signature As String

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

currentDate = Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy")
Recipients = "a@gmail.com"
CarbonCopy = "b@gmail.com"
Signature = OutMail.body

msg = "<span style='color:black'><p>Dear Team,</p>"

msg = msg & "Thank you in advance</span>"

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = Recipients
    .CC = CarbonCopy
    .Subject = "PSR " & currentDate
    .HTMLBody = "<span style = 'color:#1F497D'>" & msg & "</span>" & Signature
    .Attachments.Add ThisWorkbook.FullName
    .Display
End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature has to be declared as a variant and you have to display the empty email first to capture it.

Your "msg" isn't declared in the above code. I'm assuming you've got that covered. Otherwise your code won't work. Given that assumption...

```
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim currentDate As Date
Dim DeliveryDate As String
Dim Recipients As String
Dim CarbonCopy As String
Dim Signature As Variant

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

currentDate = Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy")
Recipients = "a@gmail.com"
CarbonCopy = "b@gmail.com"
Signature = OutMail.Body

'msg hasn't been defined so it's commented out. msg in the body has been replaced with "msg".
'msg = "<span style='color:black'><p>Dear Team,</p>"

'msg = msg & "Thank you in advance</span>"

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    'Capture signature block.
    .Display
    Signature = .HTMLBody
    .To = Recipients
    .CC = CarbonCopy
    .Subject = "PSR " & currentDate
    .HTMLBody = "<span style = 'color:#1F497D'>" & "msg" & "</span>" & Signature
    .Attachments.Add ThisWorkbook.FullName
    .Display
End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
```

Comment: Works just fine! Thanks a lot

Comment: Keep in mind that two HTML strings cannot be concatenated. They must be merged.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you cannot concatenate two HTML strings and expect a valid HTML string back. They must be merged. More than that, you also need to merge the styles etc. from two HTML documents.

Secondly, to retrieve the signature in your case, MailItem must be shown first - call `Display`, and only then read the `HTMLBody` property.

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) is an option (I am its author), it exposes [RDOSignature](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosignature.htm) object and allows to insert any signature without displaying the message using `RDOSignature.ApplyTo()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I think your mailItem does not become active. Try adding OutMail.display before you try getting the body. Then it should work.

Comment: Still no result