# Powershell, Outlook, Signature

Tags: powershell, outlook

Got this code to create a new e-mail in outlook to send from a specific account and it works perfectly.

Now, as soon as i add the "$Mail.HTMLBody = $Msg" to it, it deletes the signature and all i have is just blank text.

To me it looks like by adding the "$Msg" it replaces the whole HTLM body.

Is there a way to just add the text to the existing html body of the e-mail or a way to re-add the correct signature to the e-mail?

```
$Msg = "<span style='font-family:Calibri;font-size:12pt;'>Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren</span>"

$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$namespace = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$namespace.Logon($null, $null, $false, $true)
$EmailFrom = ('test@test.com')
$account = $outlook.Session.Accounts.Item($EmailFrom)
$Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
#$Mail.HTMLBody = $Msg
```

Comment: You have to make the signature part of what you pass in. `#$Mail.HTMLBody = $Msg`, means exactly that. [Fill the entire mail body with what is passed in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.MailItem.HTMLBody).

Comment: Is there a way maybe to use the signature from the userprofile (%appdata%\Microsoft\Signatures)?

Comment: yes, there is, and you can avoid the reg and go right to the file system. See my potential option for you. Well, outside of what `Daniel` already gave you.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51381449/adding-signature-to-an-automated-outlook-mail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook user signatures are stored here:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "$env:APPDATA\Microsoft\Signatures"
# Results
<#
    Directory: C:\Users\SomeUserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                                                              
----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                                                              
d-----         24-May-21     21:53                SomeUserName - full_files                                                                                                                             
d-----         24-May-21     21:53                SomeUserName - short_files                                                                                                                            
-a----         24-May-21     21:53          43114 SomeUserName - full.htm                                                                                                                               
-a----         24-May-21     21:53          46643 SomeUserName - full.rtf                                                                                                                               
-a----         24-May-21     21:53           1468 SomeUserName - full.txt                                                                                                                               
-a----         24-May-21     21:53          41008 SomeUserName - short.htm                                                                                                                              
-a----         24-May-21     21:53          41724 SomeUserName - short.rtf                                                                                                                              
-a----         24-May-21     21:53            120 SomeUserName - short.txt
#>
```

Thus you can examine each and determine which to use in your message body. Say something like this.

```
$UserSignature = Get-Content -Path ((Get-ChildItem -Path "$env:APPDATA\Microsoft\Signatures" -filter '*full.htm').FullName)
$Mail.HTMLBody = "$Msg`n`n
$UserSignature"
```

Comment: Note that folder name (Signatures) is localized.

Comment: This is working, but instead of the pictures (there are 2 pictures in the signature) it's just showing the frame of the size of the pic with a red "x" on the upper left corner. So its just not showing the pictures.

Comment: Are the pictures/images really needed? If not just use the .txt one. Are you saying you are doing this from any user's computer and thus, each user has a customer signature block, vs a standard corporate signature block? If it is s standard corporate signature block, pulled via ADDS attributes, then you can use Exchange to add that signature block to the outgoing mail in a Exchange routing rule, vs PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me.  I'm not sure if the registry key will work for you though or if some modification is necessary

```
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$namespace = $Outlook.GetNameSpace('MAPI')

# Get the Outlook profile name to use for looking up the signature name in the registry
$currentProfile = $Outlook.Session.CurrentProfileName

# Check the registry for the signature name to use for New mails
$reg = "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Profiles\$currentProfile\9375CFF0413111d3B88A00104B2A6676\00000002"
$signatureName = (Get-ItemProperty $reg -Name 'New Signature' ).'New Signature'

# Find the cooresponding htm signature file in appdata
$signatureFile = Get-Item "${env:APPDATA}\Microsoft\Signatures\${signatureName}.htm"

# Get the contents of the $signature file
$signature = Get-Content $signatureFile -Raw

$mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)

# Add the signature to end of the message
$Msg = "<span style='font-family:Calibri;font-size:12pt;'>Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren</span>"
$Msg += $signature

$mail.To = 'somemail@test.test'
$mail.Subject = 'Testing Signature'
$mail.HTMLBody = $Msg
$mail.Send()
```

Comment: Didn't work perfectly in my case. In the end i decided to send those mails out with text only in the signature. Thank you very much though. This might be helpfull in the future.