# How to use .HMTLBody to capture an email signature in VBA code

Tags: vba, outlook

I am attempting to capture an email signature with VBA code and insert it automatically into emails.

Based on this answer ([Outlook Email and Signature from Excel VBA - .Body vs .HTMLbody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36211195/outlook-email-and-signature-from-excel-vba-body-vs-htmlbody)), I believe the code below should function as expected - have "Add Body Here" followed by the email signature.

Although I get an error 'Application-defined or object defined error' on the line `.HTMLBody = "<p>Add Body Here.</p>" & .HTMLBody'.`

```
Dim OApp As Object
Dim OMail As Object
Dim Signature As Variant

Set OApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OMail = OApp.CreateItem(0)

With OMail
    .Display
    .Subject = "Subject"
    .HTMLBody = "<p>Add Body Here.</p>" & .HTMLBody
    .Display
End With
```

Comment: I can' see the error, but I am not an expert on this. However, this code works perfectly for me. Tell me if you want it as an answer post:

Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim tempDir As String
    Dim strbody As String
strbody = "Good morning,<p>" & _
    "Add Body Here.<p>" & _
    "Best regards,<p>"
On Error Resume Next
    
    With OutMail
        .Display
        .To = "whoever.es"
        '.CC = "whoever2.es"
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "whatever"
        .HTMLBody = strbody & .HTMLBody
    End With

Comment: should 'OApp.CreateIte(0)' be 'OApp.CreateItem(0)'

Comment: @MikeWasos I think since you are using `On Error Resume Next` then the error won't appear. Try to remove that and the error should be there

Comment: @freeflow 'OApp.CreateItem(0)' doesn't fix the issue sadly

Comment: I just used the code exactly as shown and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @CameronCritchlow Maybe it is a problem with permissions somehow?

Comment: Have to tried removing the `on error resume next` statement yet?

Comment: I do not use that statement in my code, MikeWasos added that himself

Comment: If I try to grab the signature separately (by using `Signature = .HTMLBody`) and writing the HTML as `.HTMLBody = "<p>Add Body Here.</p>" & Signature`, The error still appears on the first `Signature =` line. So the error must be with the variable assignment.

Comment: What happens if you just `.display` do you get a readable signature?

Comment: Yes, the email displays correctly and the signature appears. The error comes when trying to alter the .HTMLBody

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51381449/adding-signature-to-an-automated-outlook-mail

Answer (score 0):

First of all, call the `Display` method before making any modifications to the message body to grab the signature as is:

```
With OMail
    .Display
    .Subject = "Subject"
    .HTMLBody = "<p>Add Body Here.</p>"
End With
```

Second, there is no need to call the `Display` method twice in the code.

Third, keep in mind that `HTMLBody` property is an HTML string which represents the message body. While the OOM handles badly formatted HTML strings, the best practice to deal with a well-formatted HTML strings, so that means you need to insert the additional content right after the opening `<body>`  tag if you need to get it in the beginning or just assign it from scratch:

```
.HTMLBody = "<p>Add Body Here.</p>"
```

Comment: The above replaces the signature with the text "Add Body Here.". I am looking to keep the signature preceded by the message "Add Body Here". It appears that my code is working for others, as mentioned in the comments above. I am not sure what to check here in permissions etc?

Comment: If you want to preserve the signature or any other content you need to find the `<body>` tag and inject your content right after the tag found.

Comment: Ok, so the issue is that ‘“some text” & .HTMLBody’ is not valid HTML and I need to ensure that it is correctly formatted?

Comment: Does the code work correctly when you remove the second part with `& .HTMLBody` ?